# Capture Payment in Worldpay payment Gateway

Tags: php, fuelphp

I am implementing worldpay business gateway for my website. I have created a form and done a test transaction. Everything works fine. I got response from worldpay and I saved it in my database. Now, I want to do a capture payment. There is an option in the business manager dashboard. I can capture a payment but this is done manually. I want to know, is there any way to achieve this by code from my end?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: once you done the payment, you will call capture payment api, for more assistance check this link https://developer.worldpay.com/jsonapi/api#orders

Comment: Thanks parthi.. But I am using business gateway account https://secure.worldpay.com/sso/public/auth/login.html?serviceIdentifier=merchantadmin&maiversion=version2. Here, I cant find any api keys.

Comment: ok fine, i m not sure how its works, you will directly contact worldpay technical support person, they will help you.  Don't mistake me.....

Comment: Thank you for your time and help :)